# Click on a Specific Pixel

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to make the app click on a specific pixel?

I already searched a lot but i coudnt find anything like this in the web...

Olli

Comment: Please clarify your question: Do you want a background application to click on a specific pixel on a third-party foreground app?

Comment: no I dont want an backgroud application i want to click on a specific pixel in the normal app

Comment: @theomega How to achieve the scenario you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have found you could use the [TouchUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html) class to simulate touches and drags.